# Не срабатывает alert

Tags: javascript

Делаю расширение chrome

И не срабатывает почему то при нажатии alert. Текст Информацтя появляется.

```
function get_info(){
var lo = 'Ибо *****';
$(".profile__activeLinks")[0].innerHTML+='<div id="page__user_info" style="5px 0 0 0" onclick="javascript: alert('+lo+')"><span type="addfriend" class="profile__activeLinks_button">Информация</span></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Выводимый текст просто возьмите в кавычки:

```
function get_info(){
var lo = 'Ибо *****';
$(".profile__activeLinks")[0].innerHTML+='<div id="page__user_info" style="5px 0 0 0" onclick="javascript: alert(\"'+lo+'\")"><span type="addfriend" class="profile__activeLinks_button">Информация</span></div>';
}
```

Comment: alert(\''+lo+'\'). Поправил. На вот такой  вариант, теперь всё норм

Comment: А вот если alert поменять на функцию onclick="load_block_user()"
И в ней будет
`function load_block_user(){
var lo = 'Ибо *****';
alert(lo);
}`

Ни чего не работает